# Docker & Selenium WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 11

Tags: python, docker, selenium

I am trying to run my selenium E2E tests in docker, but I am receiveing this error and I cant figure out why. I'm using Python (Django) as my backend.

I'm on a new Mac as my old one (where I began the project) died. I git cloned the repo, so maybe there is something missing that was inside of `.gitignore` that I'm overlooking. The tests worked fine on my old Mac, but after cloning I can't get them to work.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nikolaik/python-nodejs:latest

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /my_project

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /my_project/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system


COPY . /my_project/
```

`Pipfile`:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
django = "~=3.1.0"
django-livereload-server = "*"
selenium = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /my_project/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/my_project
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 35729:35729
    depends_on:
      - selenium
  
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-firefox
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
```

My test base class includes:

```
...{Django/Selenium imports}...

class FunctionalTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    host = 'web'

    def setUp(self):
        options = Options()
        options.headless = True
        self.browser = webdriver.Remote(
            'http://selenium:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
        self.actions = ActionChains(self.browser)
```

Do I perhaps need to install Selemium locally? I can't imagine that being the problem as that defeats the point of using Docker... Any help would be appreciated.